# Cannot read property 'slickAdd' of undefined while using Slick

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

I use slickjs for making carousel.

```
<section id="slider">
</section>
<script>
$("#slider").slick("slickAdd", "<div>slide1</div>")
<script>
```

It ended up with an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slickAdd' of undefined
```

See this jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/o78gcLuu/1/

Comment: are you sure that you added slick library to your page?

Comment: @qiAlex yup. see the jsFiddle link above. i'm sure of that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used the function `.slickAdd();`
Made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3naceufb/25/) of this working example

Comment: This is the old syntax. OP's syntax is correct for 1.8+, they may have just been using an older version of slick, like Zowie is in his fiddle.